# to view list from MIN to AVG

Tags: sql, oracle

This code sorted list and output is 1, but i need to view the list

```
SELECT AVG(CustomerID) 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID =  ( SELECT  MIN(CustomerID) FROM Customers  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question you need to get `AVG` and `MIN` Value then Compare.

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM Customers T 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(CustomerID) m, AVG(CustomerID) a
    FROM Customers
) T2 ON T.CustomerID >=m AND T.CustomerID <= a
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a4d4/3)

Comment: SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID < ( SELECT  AVG(CustomerID) FROM Customers  )

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you are averaging customerid 
But still

```
select * from customers where customerid <
(SELECT avg(customerid) FROM Customers))
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_orderby3  from table Customers for example i need to select all customerID AVG and to view the list

Comment: @kapcan.88- Give your sample data and what you are  trying in  sqlfiddle

Comment: i have conditon to show all id lower than average id @ksl123